# Force the row height in the Xceed DataGridControl

Tags: xceed-datagrid

Can anybody tell me how to set the row height in the Xceed DataGridControl ? Because setting the styling for DataRow, Row, and DataCell does nothing. It seems that it's fixed at 30, and I've been unable to find any way to change it, even searching the examples that come with the grid.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways...

In the Resource:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:DataRow}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
</Style>
```

In the DataGridControl.View:

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
    <xcdg:TableflowView ContainerHeight="40" />
</xcdg:DataGridControl.View>
```

Here in the Xceed-Forum: http://xceed.com/CS/forums/post/32514.aspx